# How to write double values in lower limit of integral perfectly

Tags: errors

I am using this code but cannot get a desired output so please anyone help me out to make it correct

```
\int_{\smash[b]{\substack{\left | x-y \right |\leqslant 4t,{\left | y \right |\leqslant 2^{j+3}}}}}
```

Comment: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)

Comment: You wrote, "[I could] not get a desired output". And what would the desired output be?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\smash[b]` together with all `\left` and `\right`. Add `\\` instead of the comma to tell LaTeX where the line break should go.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{\substack{|x-y|\leqslant 4t \\ |y|\leqslant 2^{j+3}}} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]